# some commands are not working like -listavailable

Tags: powershell

Super basic question and i cannot find any solution so reaching out to the community.
When i run a command like:

Get-Module SharepointPnPPowerShellOnline –listavailable

the command completes with no errors yet won't display any version of sharepoint.
I attempted to do a writeoutput command and same thing. I don't get a result.
i currently have 3 modules installed as well and not sure if that could be an issue going forward?

C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell
C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell

I guess i just need some newbie help getting setup correctly.
Should i be running the x86 ISE?

Thanks for any and all assistance.

PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1     **strong text**

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: take a look at >>> `Get-Help Get-Module -Parameter ListAvailable` <<< ///// take note of `ListAvailable does not return information about modules that are not found in the PSModulePath environment variable, even if those modules are loaded in the current session.` ///// so ... is the module listed in `$env:PSModulePath`?